# groupadd on Ubuntu 16.04 with PBIS Open stuck with 100% CPU

Tags: 16.04, active-directory, groups

I have Ubuntu 16.04 servers and workstations which are members of an Active Directory domain, using *PowerBroker PBIS Open* versions 8.5.0.153 and 8.6.0.427. When I try to add a local group using *groupadd someNewGroup* I see it stuck at 100% CPU. If I specify a group number explicitly with *-g* then it works fine.

On two other virtual hosts which are actually Proxmox 4.4 containers - a CentOS 7 with PBIS 8.5.0 and Ubuntu 16.04 with PBIS 8.5.2.265 I can add and delete local groups freely with no issues.

With *strace* I see the that it's stuck after performing a seek on */etc/group*:

```
open("/etc/group", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 8
open("/etc/default/nss", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 9
fstat(9, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1756, ...}) = 0
read(9, "# /etc/default/nss\n# This file c"..., 4096) = 1756
read(9, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(9)                                = 0
futex(0x7f2aaefa9a50, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
lseek(8, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
fstat(8, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=882, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 882, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 8, 0) = 0x7f2ab0764000
lseek(8, 882, SEEK_SET)                 = 882
```

What's wrong here? How can I get groupadd to work properly?

Comment: Just throwing this out there - have you run `grpck` to see if it spots any inconsistencies in the local group / gshadow files?

Comment: The problem persists even though _grpck_ reports no error.